# How to cp remaining files after failed attempt

Tags: cp

I'm trying to copy a large directory from one drive to another. I mistakenly logged out before it was finished so only about 80% of the files copied over. Is there away to copy the remaining files without starting from scratch?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would try,

```
rsync -a /from/file /dest/file
```

you can use other options like `--append`, `-P (--partial --progress)`. See [man rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for more info.

Or if you are using `cp` then use `cp -u`.

from `man cp`:

```
-u, --update
     copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing.
```

Comment: I'll have to give it to Rahul cus he just beat you to it, but thanks and everyone gets an upvote!

Comment: If the first copy ended abruptly, one of the files may be copied only partially, and `cp -u` might not care, since it only checks timestamps, not the size... So you'd need to `touch` the source files first if you have to use it. (Or just use `rsync`.)

Comment: @ilkkachu that's right. I will update it soon.

Comment: Does cp ever leave a single file only partially transfered? If it does, then -u seems like it would leave you with a directory that was only partially working.

Answer (score 16):

For partial file transfers, `cp` might not be what you need.

I suggest using `rsync` instead. Even when transfer fails, you can simply re-run the command at a later time, and it'll copy only the missing files.

Example:

```
$ rsync -aPEmivvz from/ to/
```

*(will copy `from/` into `to/` directory)*

Since `rsync` does syncing and checking after each transfer, ensuring files have been copied correctly is trivial.

The swich set `-aPEmivvz` is my standard *go-to* selection, whenever copying files over networks or external drives, including plug-in devices, like SD-Cards, etc.

These are the switches I use almost always:

`-a`: "archive", includes `-rlptgo` (recursive, symlinks as symlinks, permissions, times, group, owner)

`-P`: "partial progress" shows nice progress bar for each file

`-E`: "executability" preserve whether executable or not

`-m`: "noempty" prunes empty dirs

`-i`: "summary" print change summary for all updates

`-vv`: "more verbose"

`-z`: "compression"

Answer (score 6):

What you probably want rather than `cp` in this case is `rsync`.

Just recursively copying one directory structure to a new location:

```
rsync -av /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `cp` for this. As others have stated it's not the right tool for the job. The correct tool is going to depend on your goals.

If you just want a straight copy:

`rsync /source /destination` with some level of flags. See the other answers for some really good examples.

If you want to have bi-directional updates

`unison` is the way to go. Rsync doesn't do very well at conflict resolution with bidirectional syncs. Specially deletes. So you you want bi-directional copies fire up `unison`

If you want backups and the files are text based, then you can try using `git`. Git can be run locally, there's no need for a "server". In fact, git servers are only file sharing methods. You could totally have a git repo on the backup drive and "push" to it. Again this only really works if the files are text based and your trying to get a one way backup.

Again if your going for a backup (and not just one time) then look at deja-dupe, BackIntime, or similar options. They take snapshots of the data at a point in time. They all run rsync under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

You can also copy all files again, ask for confirmation for each overwrite, then automatically answer no to the question:

```
yes n | cp -i /source /dest
```

(you have probably used more options, like `-r`, so just add them like `cp -pri /source /dest` ...)

Answer (score 3):

Use the command `rsync` with the following options:

```
rsync --progress --partial --append /source_file /destination_file
```